# why am I getting free(): invalid pointer error after program ends

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

Can somebody explain why I'm getting this error after program ends?

> free(): invalid pointer

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    int a = 3;
    std::unique_ptr<int> up(&a);
    
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << *up << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << &a << std::endl;
    std::cout << up.get() << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::unique_ptr<int> up(&a);
```

The whole and entire purpose of `std::unique_ptr`, the only reason it exists, is so that when it goes out of scope and gets destroyed it automatically `delete`s whatever it's pointing to (assuming that it hasn't been moved from).

`a` was instantiated in function local scope, and not dynamic scope, hence attempting to `delete`, what was not `new`ed, results in undefined behavior, and your crash.

Comment: does this mean we have to use `std::unique_ptr` only for dynamically allocated memory?

Comment: That's exactly what it means, and that's the only reason that `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` exists: to prevent memory leaks by `delete`ing, automatically, once all (unique/shared) pointers to the object are gone. It won't make much sense to use them, if the pointed-to objects were not dynamically allocated, doesn't it?

Comment: is it possible to get a compile time error(warning) for doing such mistakes. I mean like cannot assign a local variable (stack allocated variable) address to `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: Theoretically it is possible, but no C++ compiler has any obligation to issue a diagnostic when compiling code that results in undefined behavior. C++ compilers are very smart and can catch many errors, but there is no limit to the kind of bugs that can occur. Even the smartest C++ compiler can't possibly know that, for example, `std::unique_ptr` gets constructed with a pointer that was initialized by a separately-compiled `.cpp` file, where it points to a static object. That's something that only LTO can catch, but, again, I would not expect a C++ compiler to catch this kind of an error.

Answer (score 1):

This is a toy model of a unique pointer:

```
struct toy_ptr {
    int* p;
    ~toy_ptr() { delete p; }
};
```

("toy" because much more is needed, while this is only what is needed to reproduce your problem)

Now if you do this:

```
int main() {

    int a = 0;
    toy_ptr ptr{&a};
}
```

the `toy_ptr` takes ownership of `a`. Owning an object means: the `toy_ptr` is responsible for deleting it in its destructor. `a` was not allocated via `new`, hence attempting to delete it via `delete &a` invokes undefined behavior.

A `unique_ptr` is not a `toy_ptr`, but it also does take ownership of the pointer passed to the constructor and it does attempt to delete it in its destructor.